# Arrays(initialization) in gmp

Tags: c, gmp

How could one initialize and set an array at the same time?
I'm looking for something equivalent to this:

```
int mat[2][2]={{1,1},{1,0}};
```

in mpz_t.
Cheers.

Comment: Do you normally initialise by a function call? Looking at the data type in he header file shows it has `mp_limb_t *_mp_d;` which seems to suggest that it won't be simple to manually initialise it.

Comment: Normally,vars are initialized via the mpz_init(var) command,I think it might work for array's as well,but certainly the usual syntax won't work.So to set values, I have to do it one by one.I'll look a bit deeper into this,there must be an alternative.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpz_t is more or less opaque to you, and it requires function calls to initialize.

So you can't initialize it with a C initializer.